# CakePHP: BeforeSave and AfterSave on entire save?

Tags: cakephp, callback

I'm having an issue with a misbehaving behavior.  The short of it is that I am hooking into the beforeSave and afterSave callbacks using a behavior, but this has unintended consequences for my situation.  Is it possible to replicate this?

```
$this->Model->bsCallback();
if ($this->Model->saveAll($this->data)) { // Model might have other related models
    $this->Model->asCallback();
}
```

Note that asCallback() would run after saving Model and all related models.  That's been my stumbling block, my afterSave in my behavior that is attached to my Model is being called too early and not obtaining data from the related models (because it hasn't been written yet).  Putting helper in the model related to Model helps, but I can't be guarantee that the related model would be touched on save, or if it was that all of the models related to Model will have updated by that time.

So yeah, how do I do 'beforeSave' and 'afterSave' correctly on a save that touches multiple models?

Comment: Are you actually calling those callbacks by hand as in your above code, or is that just for illustrational purposes? What is it you want to do in those callbacks?

Comment: It's just for illustrative purposes. I was wondering if there was any way to do the equivalent without having to write out that code before and after every save. I basically want to take a snapshot of the model and related models in question both before the save and after the save, serialize it, and put it in a 'logging' table. So yeah, I need to be able to get a 'before' and 'after' on the model and all related models, because if I hit an afterSave before a related model has been saved then that leaves me with only half the changes logged.

Answer (score 0):

In standard PHP you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), as here:

```
ob_start();

include('a_page.php');
do_some_stuff();

// $data now holds all output and nothing is output at this point.
$data = ob_get_clean();

$this->Model->beforeSave($data);
$this->Model->saveAll($data);
$this->Model->afterSave($data);
```